# WPF Image Binding & Converter Not working

Tags: c#, wpf

```
  //in xaml
  //resource
  <local:LocalUriToImageConverter x:Key="MyImageConverter"/>
  //datacontext
  DataContext="{x:Static local:GlobalData.CustomServiceInfo}"
  //image **exception throw at UriSource ** 
  <Image Height="60" Width="60" >
            <Image.Resources>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding HeadPicUrl , Converter={StaticResource MyImageConverter}}" x:Key="image1"  />
                <FormatConvertedBitmap Source="{StaticResource image1}" x:Key="formattedImage" DestinationFormat="Gray32Float" />
            </Image.Resources>
            <Image.Style>
                <Style  TargetType="Image">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource image1}"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource formattedImage}"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
  </Image>

  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //Code
  //model
  public class CustomServiceInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string HeadPicUrl { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }

    }
 //init
 public MainWindow()
        {

        GlobalData.CustomServiceInfo = new CustomServiceInfo {
            Name = "nainaigu",
            HeadPicUrl = @"http://avatar.csdn.net/0/5/5/1_haifengzhilian.jpg",
            Status = true ,
            //Type = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + "MahAppsDemo" + ";component/" + "Image/my.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
            //Type = "pack://application:,,,/" + "MahAppsDemo" + ";component/" + "Image/my.jpg"
        };

        InitializeComponent();
      }

   //Custom Coverter 
   public class LocalUriToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string path = (string)value;
            int BytesToRead = 100;
            try
            {
                var image = new BitmapImage();
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute));
                request.Timeout = -1;
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(responseStream);
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

                byte[] bytebuffer = new byte[BytesToRead];
                int bytesRead = reader.Read(bytebuffer, 0, BytesToRead);

                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    memoryStream.Write(bytebuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = reader.Read(bytebuffer, 0, BytesToRead);
                }

                image.BeginInit();
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                image.StreamSource = memoryStream;
                image.EndInit();
                return image;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return new BitmapImage();
            }

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

the exception msg is `{"must set the “UriSource” or “StreamSource”."}`.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWG30.png)

i think the convert is not woring because i set the debug point in the Convert method，but the exception throw Before this。
i don't know where went wrong in my code above.
this is my first question in stackoverflow. 
please help me.thanks！

Comment: Exceptions comes with stack traces, and you should always provide _complete_ information about any errors and exceptions. Including the stack trace. As for the converter, that's quite a converter you've got there; you really should be handling that a different way...the converter should not include complex, time-consuming operations like that. If you want more help with this, please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: I am sorry . i remenber that.this is my first time.could you tell me how to edit my question agin.

Comment: Please see the link that reads ["edit"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34101843/edit) at the bottom of your post.

Comment: thanks.i edit again.and add a picture about exption.

Comment: Why have you defined `BitmapImage` and `FormatConvertedBitmap` in Image.Resouces?

Comment: i want binding the model.when status is false,let the picture to grey.is not like that?

Comment: I believe those should not be part of Image.Resource. Those should be direct child of Image tag.

Comment: thanks.i change to --- <Image Width="45" Height="45" 
               x:Name="headPicture"  Cursor="Hand" Source="{Binding HeadPicUrl, Converter={StaticResource MyImageConverter}}" >
            </Image> --- then solve the problem.

Comment: What's the sense of the converter? WPF can already load an ImageSource from an Uri, or URI string, or local file path without a converter, Just bind the Image.Source property to a string or Uri property, the conversion is done automatically behind the scenes.

Comment: @Clemens yes, WPF can do that.i trying to binding the uri string for BitmapImage ,like this: `<BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding HeadPicUrl , Converter={StaticResource MyImageConverter}}" x:Key="image1"  />` .i put it into the Image.Resouces.but the exception was happed.i want to know why.

Comment: @Clemens i use the converter because the image path（in my case it is a http url） can be changed by the code. it can not be hardcoding into the xaml.

Comment: You can bind the Source property of the Image control to a property of type string (as you did) without a converter. There's no hardcoding involved. As long as the property raises a property change notification, the image will be updated by the binding. All that works out of the box without a binding converter, as long as the source property is of type string, Uri, byte[] or ImageSource and holds a valid image URI or data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child controls are defined in Image.Resources instead in Image. Please update the xaml code as follows:

```
<Image Width="45" Height="45" x:Name="headPicture" Cursor="Hand" Source="{Binding HeadPicUrl, Converter={StaticResource MyImageConverter}}" >               
            <Image.Style>
                <Style  TargetType="Image">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource image1}"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource formattedImage}"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
  </Image>
```

Comment: why can not  put  `<BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding HeadPicUrl , Converter={StaticResource MyImageConverter}}" x:Key="image1"  />` into the Image.Resouces. this was allowed  by the ide.just is a Compile error.i load an ImageSource from http URI string and pass it to a converter.i think it is ok.i want to know where went wrong.